# Redux-Form initialValues not working with redux-form/immutable

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, immutable.js

**The problem**
https://codesandbox.io/s/3o4j9y375

**What I have**

Ok, this one is really tricky... I have the following code :

```
Form = connect((state, props) => ({
  formValues: getFormValues('myForm')(state),
  initialValues: props.values,
}))(Form);
```

**What I expect**

Having in my Form props both formValues and initialValues.

**Where did it go wrong?**

First I just wanted formValues to be in my Form props : I encountered an issue with that because i am using IMMUTABLE so I had to import like this

```
import { getFormValues } from 'redux-form/immutable';
```

Instead of like this

```
import { getFormValues } from 'redux-form';
```

Once that fixed I wanted to add some initialValues to my form as showed above and THAT is is the problem.
I console logged my props in Form and initialValues are passed but not in the JSON format that I used but in an IMMUTABLE MAP...
But in this format, the values are not injected in the form.

**TL/DR**

**import redux-form/immutable ->** can use getFormValues but initialValues are stored as immutable Map so not working

**import redux-form ->** cannot use getFormValues but initialValues are stored in JSON so it's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use formValueSelector https://redux-form.com/7.4.2/docs/api/formvalueselector.md/

`import { formValueSelector } from 'redux-form/immutable'`

`const selector = formValueSelector('myForm');`

`const mapStateToProps = (state) {
  formValues: selector('myForm')(state),
}`

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Form);`

Comment: or you can use get('formValues') on your immutable object.